# Jenkins if conditions; ksh script

Tags: jenkins, ksh

After build, I have Jenkins run a script if the build is successful and if it's the weekend, invoke another script. This alone works fine, but when I introduce the weekend checking, it breaks.

I tried:

```
if [[ $(date +%u)>5 ]]
then
 bash ~/run.sh 
else
 echo "Not weekend"
fi
```

I also tried

```
if [[ $(date +%u) -gt 5 ]]
```

But it doesn't seem like Jenkins likes this

```
ksh: syntax error at line 1: `]]
' unexpected
```

Comment: Tell us what happens when you run `[[ 7 -gt 5 ]] && echo ok || echo no` in an interactive `ksh.`   Also run `ksh --version`. If this does not produce something like `version sh (AT&T Research) 93t+ 2010-06-21` you may have 
a ksh _clone_ that does not support all syntax from the original.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you put CR-LF (“DOS” or “ASCII”) line endings in there somewhere, so you really have an \r (^M) behind the “]]” which is, of course, not recognised.